# Does 「天使が好きを見るで人間は。」 mean "Angels like to look at humans"

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence

So I just randomly thought of something to write and this popped up. My thought process behind it is that 「天使」 means angel and angels are the ones performing the liking so I put 「が好き」 to get "Angels like". Then Angels are also the ones doing the looking so 「を見る」 or "to look". Then followed by 「人間は」 "Humans". In all from my rough understanding of Japanese and particles I think this should mean along the lines of "The Angels like to look at [the] humans". Is this correct or would it at least be understood? Also could you please correct any mistakes with the reasoning behind them. Thank you!

Comment: It took me a close look to guess you probably meant 人間は天使が好き (which can roughly mean "Humans like angels"), but the 見るで part still made no sense. In short, your intended message is not displayed, and the sentence structure is quite awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to map English grammar onto Japanese in a way that doesn't make sense. The は particle never comes at the end of a sentence, and 好き is not a verb. Here's what you're after:

天使は人間を見るのが好きだ。

Depending on the context, this could also mean that angels like to look after or keep an eye on humans. If you mean that they enjoy gazing upon the human form, you might consider 眺める or 見つめる rather than 見る.

If you're interested in a primer on Japanese grammar, check out [Imabi.net](http://imabi.net/) or [Tae Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar).